# Refreshing a jsp on some change

Tags: jsp

How can I refresh a jsp on any change automatically?
Is there any way to do it?

In my application I am  using JSP to design the header.
Now as per requirement I have to make a change in the jsp which is only reflecting when Iam manually refreshing the page.

I want this to be done automatically.

Comment: You cant refresh page automatically , unless you use timer kind of stuffs in it or you need a ajax for it

Answer (score 1):

> I have to make a change in the jsp which is only reflecting when Iam manually refreshing the page

Because once you run the jsp file , it renders the `html` content to the browser and it doesnt maintain any active connection with the browser unless you are creating a new request.

> How can I refresh a jsp on any change automatically? Is there any way to do it?

You can use [**Ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) as it is meant for this purpose.

Poll the server for regular intervals using the [window.setInterval](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) method and update the contents.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: <c:if test="${commandObject.function.functionCode =='ELOG WELCOME'}">
  <td align="left" width="28">
   <img src="assets/images/welcome/kewill_logo_1.png" width="36" height="28" alt="Logo" position = "center"/>
  </td>
  </c:if>

Comment: if i want to refresh complete jsp is it possible .

Comment: yes it is possible . but probably ajax is not used for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to achieve specifically here, you will have to use Javascript in your **.jsp** page.

If by 'refreshing', you mean literally refreshing the page as if the user clicked the browser's refresh button, then you can use this Javascript code.

```
 location.reload();
```

What you'll need to do is capture events, in your page, that should cause the page to reload, and then execute the Javascript command above when they occur.

This being said, **san krish** (above answer, at the moment I'm writing this) suggested AJAX. It is very likely that AJAX is actually the solution you're looking for -- what AJAX means is that you'll use Javascript to only refresh a *specific part of the page*, instead of reloading the entire page. In a nutshell, AJAX means using Javascript to make requests and retrieve the responses without 'leaving' the page. It's a bit complex to explain shortly, especially given that we are not sure what you are trying to build at the moment, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: <c:if test="${commandObject.function.functionCode =='ELOG WELCOME'}"> <td align="left" width="28"> <img src="assets/images/welcome/kewill_logo_1.png" width="36" height="28" alt="Logo" position = "center"/> </td> </c:if>

Comment: the above code is changing an image in the jsp based on a test condition. Now as this is an html content the image doesn't change automatically when the condition fails unless user refreshes the page automatically.

Comment: OK. Well essentially, you just need to hook the location.reload() command to whatever actions on your page.